# svg and HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html

I started on a new project in order to get reports in javascript. I need to download the data I display in a PDF. In the html page, I have svg charts from Google charts (svg) and others html code. I want all this data in a pdf. I tried to used jspdf with pdf export and html2canvas. I obtain the svg charts in the pdf but all the html around it is in a black content.

I generate my google chart in the div with the id 'pc-by-modele' and I display the table in javascript too.
Here is my code:

```
 <div id="main-container">
    <div id="chart-model"></div>
     <div class="shadow-z-1 box-container">
       <table id="pc-by-modele">
         <tr>
           <th>MODELE</th>
           <th>PC NUMBER</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>

<script lang="javascript" src="public/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script lang="javascript" src="public/javascript/pdfexport.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript" src="public/javascript/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript" src="public/javascript/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.generatePDF = function generatePDF() {
            var format = 'a4';
            var pdfExport = new PDFExport(format);
            var domNode = document.getElementById('main-container');
            pdfExport.createPageScreenshot(domNode).then(function () {
                pdfExport.downloadDocument();
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: use pdfmake plugin http://pdfmake.org for saving and downloading into pdf format